# Where do I ask a question about what strategy I should use in programming?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I would like to ask the following question, but I feel like I'm not sure if it's okay to ask here. If it's not okay to ask here, is there a different SE where this would be acceptable to ask?

> I'm a CS student about to graduate. My college doesn't teach much web programming.  My friend asked me to make his website for him in exchange for food/drinks/etc. He is a photographer and wants his website to have **all** of the 7k+ photos he's got. He wants them to be tagged with various things like landscape/portrait, location, subject matter, B&W/color, etc. He wants to be able to easily add more photos with their respective classifications on his own since I won't always be around to maintain his site.
>
> I was thinking that I should make a SQL database with each photo's ID number, any classifications it has been given, and the filename in a directory. Then to display the photos I was thinking about using this jQuery plugin called [Galleriffic](http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/index.html) But Im kind of confused about if this is the best way or if it's even feasible.
>
> What would be the best, or the some of the best, ways to approach this?

Can I ask this on Stack Overflow? It's sort of about the pre-programming planning stage to me but I feel like I often perceive these things differently than other people.

Comment: No.  You'll have to get it started first.  You'll possibly find out that those 7000 photos are a major drain and make the web server keel over with just 20 people visiting it at the same time.  Now you have a *real* problem.  One you can document, everybody expects you to show the profiler results.  And you'll get a good answer.  That's useful to a *lot* more people.  And yourself, you're 30% to getting to be an expert on web site load.  A very marketable skill and one you can make a living at without anybody's help.  It requires *you* to take the initiative.

Comment: For starters, it would be a good idea to remove the information like `I'm a CS student about to graduate. My college doesn't teach much web programming. My friend asked me to make his website for him in exchange for food/drinks/etc.` (How is it relevant to the question?) Besides that- the question is much too broad to be asked on Stack Overflow, but is *closer* to being asked on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/): you should read their [What topics can I ask about](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page and the rest of their Help Center

Comment: Check wordpress and http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-create-an-image-gallery-in-wordpress/

Comment: tell your friend to check out smugmug, x1, and the other web sites that specialize in photographer portfolios.

Comment: @Confused In my editing of your post, I've also modified your example question to fix a few little things: if you'd prefer it in its original form, feel free to rollback my edits.

Comment: @DavidRobinson even then, I'd suspect that it would get closed as [too broad](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6490/40980) on P.SE too.  In general, if a question is closed for one of the common reasons P.SE and SO share, if it would be migrated to the other site, it would be closed for the same reason.

Comment: I would greatly protest the grounds for closing my question. I read the other question before posting and this is an EXTREMELY specific situation.

Comment: I included the info about CS student stuff because the first response will be that I didn't provide enough info about my background and skill level to know if I'm looking for something like smugmug (Which btw will do nothing for me having something to show for looking for a job) or something like a JQuery plug in or a PHP coding approach.